# I have a react-native project, when using VoiceOver on an iPad the element highlight doesn't highlight the whole element

Tags: react-native, voiceover

I have a react-native project (v0.68.5). When using VoiceOver on an iPhone the element that will be read out is highlighted with a black box. This highlights the elements fine on an iPhone and on an iPad when it is in portrait orientation. The issue is when the iPad is in horizontal orientation the highlight doesn't hightlight the whole element, as shown in the image below.

[iPad horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7uxj.png)

It seems like the highlight has a max-width as on horizontal iPad smaller elements are selected correctly.

I've looked through the solution to see if any styling is causing this but it impacts all elements. I therefore think it has something to do with how react-native implements VoiceOver.